# Duplicate columns in Oracle query using row limiting clause

Tags: sql, oracle, pagination

Since Oracle 12c, we can finally use the SQL standard row limiting clause like this:

```
SELECT * FROM t FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY
```

Now, in Oracle 12.1, there was a limitation that is quite annoying when joining tables. It's not possible to have two columns of the same name in the `SELECT` clause, when using the row limiting clause. E.g. this raises ORA-00918 in Oracle 12.1

```
SELECT t.id, u.id FROM t, u FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY
```

[This is a restriction is documented in the manual for all versions 12.1, 12.2, 18.0](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6__BABHFGAA):

[image]

The workaround is obviously to alias the columns

```
SELECT t.id AS t_id, u.id AS u_id FROM t, u FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY
```

Or to resort to "classic" pagination using `ROWNUM` or window functions.

Curiously, though, the original query with ambiguous `ID` columns runs just fine from Oracle 12.2 onwards. Is this a documentation bug, or an undocumented feature?

Comment: To add to the confusion, search MoS for bug 13687511. That isn't visible itself but there are two linked bugs which seem to be about this behaviour, one of which implies they documented the behaviour (18688513: Closed, Documentation Bug Fixed). But there are also patches for it, which makes it seem more likely the behaviour was changed/fixed in 12.2 onwards. So, it sounds like a documentation bug, unless there are scenarios where it can still happen. I don't think you'll get a definitive answer without raising an SR (or reporting a doc bug) though.

Comment: Probably only something Oracle can answer :]

Comment: My guess is that Oracle -- behind the scenes -- is producing some kind of structure to hold or define the table before delivering the rows. It's like when you try to create a view with duplicate column names.

Comment: @TheImpaler: It was simply a bug in early implementations. Indeed, I also think that this is caused by the emulation of the feature through using window functions in derived tables (which do not allow for ambiguous column names)

Comment: Here is some additional information from [AskTom](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/asktom.search?tag=duplicate-columns-in-oracle-query-using-row-limiting-clause)

Answer (score 1):

Seems in this case when you are using the row limiting clause, Oracle internally calling the `ROW_NUMBER()` function where it using the column name in `OVER` clause Like `ROW_NUMBER OVER(ORDER BY ID)`. because of this you are getting the `ORA-00918 error`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That definitely explains it and is the most likely reason. But this $$$ product should be able to define intermediate column identifiers for disambiguation, right? :-) Which it does from 12.2 onwards. My question is simply: Has this been fixed (but manual not updated), or does this now work accidentally

Comment: I am not sure on this, but seems they have fixed this.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that you have an implicit join. It would be interesting to see if the problem goes away when joining explicitly. I'm wondering if behind the scenes Oracle is doing a join based on id=id and not using the table aliases you assigned them.

That would also explain the column aliases fixing the issue. Try explicitly joining; that could force oracle to use the table aliases and resolve the ambiguity it thinks it sees.

Comment: That would be even worse, given that the described behaviour is *documented*